# Is it possible to use a javascript loop to open a website, excecute a function several times?

Tags: javascript, function, console, settimeout

I'm trying to make a script where I can access a bunch of links, and excecute the same script on alle websites.
I've tried to implement the 'this.document.location = "";' function, but every it seems like it's not possible to open more than one website each time I run the script.
Using the setTimeout() function, it would still just open one of the websites.

If I have an array of strings, how would it be possible to iterate through all the links, until I've executed the script on all the websites?

Comment: Are those links all on the same domain?

Comment: @Zach Can you clarify? Are the links all on the same domain, or not? I have an answer either way, but knowing the situation first will help

Comment: If you ask for help, it's generally a good idea to answer clarification requests [soon](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive), otherwise you're much less likely to get a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be locking for an iframe. You can run a script from a parent to a child. your page --- contains ---> iframe ---> another website.

Some websites won't load inside an iframe due to [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) and some restrictions also enforce if the website your loading is not part of the same domain. If part of the same domain, you can execute javascript code.

Comment: I did try doing that, but the website wouldn't let me. I was trying to run the script in the console. It was possible to use the script on the website, and I could use another script to open a new website, but every time I was just able to do it once. I would like to be able to go through several websites